# Strange glitching effect on bezier circle in edit mode

Tags: rigging, bezier-curves

so I'm rigging this little walker creature I made. When I added a bezier circle for the path the rig will follow this weird magenta and red line showed up, pointing away from the circle. It only shows up in edit mode and disappears when I select all vertices on the curve.

I'm inclined to believe that it's harmless because it seems to only be visual but I don't wanna ignore it and have it somehow ruin my project file.

[image: Screenshot of the glitch in question]

Edit: Here is the link to the file in question.
[image]

Selecting the bezier circle and going into edit mode should make the glitch appear, I found that the glitch to be only visible when the rest of the armature is visible.

Comment: That looks like a graphics problem to me. Check that you have the latest drivers installed for your graphics  card.

Comment: ..have to agree with John.. check your drivers first .. this looks like a hardware / configuration problem, or possibly a bug. In those cases, it would be off-topic on BSE. But just in case it isn't, could you strip down a minimal version of your file consistently showing the problem, and share it on https://blend-exchange.com/, editing the link into your post. Then we can see if we can reproduce the effect on our own installations.